# how to access property from usestate hook with json like object

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

i kinda new in react native. i want to make function that show cards with just feeding them list. for testing, i use usestate.it meant to be json. but somehow i cant access the property on the object.

```js
 const [data,setData]= useState([
        {ob1:[  {key:'1b',value:true,text:'data'},
                {key:'2b',value:true,text:'data'},
                {key:'3b',value:true,text:'data'},
                {key:'4b',value:true,text:'data'},
        ]},
        {ob3:[  {key:'1b',value:true,text:'data'},
            {key:'2b',value:true,text:'data'},
            {key:'3b',value:true,text:'data'},
            {key:'4b',value:true,text:'data'},
        ]}
    ])

    const Show =()=>{
        
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
                {Object.entries(data).map(([key,value])=>(
                    <Grid_ver color={'yellow'}>
                        <Grid_hor id={value.ob1.key} color={'yellow'}>
                           //some <Text>

                        </Grid_hor>
                    </Grid_ver>
                ))}
            </View>
        )
    }
```

on the function Show(), Object.entries(data) just doing fine. but i cant access value to use in <Grid_hor>.
somehow i got snipset like this.

```js
const data: ({
    ob1: {
        key: string;
        value: boolean;
        text: string;
    }[];
    ob3?: undefined;
} | {
    ob3: {
        key: string;
        value: boolean;
        text: string;
    }[];
    ob1?: undefined;
})[]
```

i tried Object.entries(data.ob1), Object.entries(data[0]), but still cant access the property.

i really glad if anyone give me some tips. hehe... thanks...

Comment: i edit it for more context on <Grid_hor>... i forgor before...

Comment: guys... i tought the problem was the data. i tried to access anywhere and still cant.. so.. what make this data error? it seem json-like to me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for existence of `data.obj1` and `data.obj3` first because the keys are not guaranteed to exist based on the JSON you wrote. You can check for truthiness and then access as normal:

```js
if (data.obj1 != null) {
  return (
    <Grid_hor>obj1 exists! key: {data.obj1.key}</Grid_hor>
  );
}

if (data.obj3 != null) {
  return (
    <Grid_hor>obj3 exists! key: {data.obj3.key}</Grid_hor>
  );
}
```

Comment: where should i place this validator? before the function or inside?

Answer (score 0):

i post the answer for who face the same problem. so, maybe json have very strict rule for bracket and quote. i like to use single quote. but unfortunately i have to use double quote. Here the solution...

```
const [data,setDat]= useState([
        {
            "ob1":
                  [
                    { "key":"1a", "value":"true","text":"data"},
                    { "key":"2a", "value":"true","text":"data"},
                    { "key":"3a", "value":"true","text":"data"},
                    { "key":"4a", "value":"true","text":"data"}
                  ],
            "ob3":
                  [
                    { "key":"1b", "value":"true","text":"data"},
                    { "key":"2b", "value":"true","text":"data"},
                    { "key":"3b", "value":"true","text":"data"},
                    { "key":"4b", "value":"true","text":"data"}
                  ]
          } 
    ])
```